# Inconsistant results using HTML5 Video on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, dom, webrtc

I am attempting to test the basic getUserMedia() function on Firefox. I am getting the strangest results for my test.

I am running the following Javascript code:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia

                    || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
/*
 * Set up desired constraints
 */
var constraints = { audio:false,video:true };

/*
 * This function to be called upon successful stream creation(?)
 */
function madeStream(aStream) {
   var video = document.querySelector("video");
   window.stream = aStream;

   video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(aStream);

   /*
    * At this point, we play the video!
    */
    video.play();
}

/*
 * This function is to be called should the attempt to create the stream fail.
 */
function failureWarning(theFail) {
    alert("Failed to get user media! "+theFail);
}

if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints,madeStream,failureWarning);
}
else
{
   alert("This video function is not supported on this browser!");
}
```

My HTML file uses the basic video tag:

```
<video autoplay></video>
```

I've checked the code several times against API documentation. As far as I know I am using it correctly.

The problem is, that the video does not behave consistently across my browsers. This inconsistency is not between different browsers, but between installations of the same browser!

I am attempting to run this test on 4 different machines:

Machine 1 is a Macintosh that is running Firefox Version 31.0

Machine 2 is a Windows machine running Windows 7 and Firefox Version 31.0

Machine 3 is a Windows laptop that is running Windows 8.0 and Firefox Version 31.0

Machine 4 is a Windows laptop that is running Windows 81 and Firefox Version 31.0

Note for emphasis: all machines are using Firefox Version 31.0.

All machines, when accessing the web page, properly request access to the camera (note: in my constraints the audio is set to false).

When I grant access on Machine 1, I see the local video.

When I grant access on Machine 2, I see nothing.

When I grant access on Machine 3, I see the local video.

When I grant access on Machine 4, I see nothing.

Important note: The camera turns on on all machines. Debugging the Javascript code, I see that the MediaStream object is successfully acquired and that the video play function is successfully called.

Further debugging reveals that the video source is dynamically changed to reflect the acquired MediaStream object. A typical result of adding the object to the video tag is shown below:

```
<video src="mediastream:f7b34f2e-55d5-9148-ae7c-dfec4e436dde" autoplay=""></video>
```

This all happens in the same way on all machines, again all running the same version of Firefox.

I have further discovered that when the video tag is first rendered on the browser it appears as an empty Flash object. On Machines 1 and 3, this object changes to a working MediaStream video the moment the video tag's source is changed. For some reason, on Machines 2 and 4, the video tag does not update, but continues showing as a Flash object which remains empty (appearing to show nothing).

This is obviously inconsistent behavior on the part of the Firefox browser. Unfortunately, while I know what is happening, I do not know why it is happening. I am sure there is something on Machines 2 and 4 that is causing them to fail to update the video tag, but I cannot see what it could be. I need to find out what it is about these machines that is determining whether or not the MediaStream video will display, in order to get the machines to all behave consistently.

It isn't the Firefox version because they are all the same version.

It isn't the operating system because one is working on a Macintosh and another on a version of Windows.

Can anyone think of another factor or configuration that is causing the video to work on one machine and fail on another?

Someone please advise.